# Incoming call notification like WhatsApp in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, agora.io

I have implemented Audio and video call using Agora for Android and iOS. What I need now a way to show notification with Accept and Reject buttons for calls.
I have been searching around and found callkeep, flutter-callkeep and flutter_voip_kit but they are using built-in phone app. I want to do it like whatsapp or skype. Can anyone help me out and guide me in right direction. Thanks

Comment: Let's start with this. I think you'll need to instantiate a new flutter engine yourself, and give it the proper parameters to load. Have you checked the flutter docs? I think I've read something similar, but can't remember where

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did try something like this recently, will share my insights.
Some points about WhatsApp call in the latest android versions:

1. Only when the phone is locked you will get a full-screen call notification
2. For other cases you will get a notification with accept or reject buttons

So the main thing you would need is a message transfer method, for which you could use [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package.

For notifying the user you could use [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) package

Comment: can you provide me the sample of code... i am stuck on this from last 5 days.

Comment: its been so long and hope you found the solution, if so, please help me doing the same